# style on GridView gets lost on paging

Tags: jquery, gridview

I am using GridView bound to sqldatasrc (with paging). On a button click I apply styles on a few rows using jquery, when I go to page 2 and reurn to page 1, i see the styles are no more there. This is due to postback.

How can i retain these styles when i move between pages.

Please support answer with code.

Answer (score 2):

How do I store that? Let me explain this in detail. The user is on page 1. He decides to apply style on a few rows randomnly. User applies styles just by clicking the row. Now he moves to page 2. He applies the style there too. Now when he goes back to page 1, he should be able to see the row with styles.

How do i save a history of the rows styles when moving across pages?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you answered your own question. You applied the styles to a few rows on a button click. So if you go to page 2 on your grid and come back to page one, you need to re-fire that click event or just run the routine that applies the styles to the rows.