# GridView Styles get lost when click on Edit Command Control

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, edit

I have a nearly *perfect* GridView until Edit Command Control is clicked. Then the columns' widths get wider and extremely out of alignment. What is causing this behaviour?

Before Edit

[image]

After Edit

[image]

**EDIT to Question:**

When Click on Edit, the editable columns are *wired up* with a TextBox control as per the following code snippet:

```
(TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[0]
```

Based on [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/452658/1389394) I sort of figure out that perhaps the styling isn't being fired when `Row_Editing` event is fired. But I am not sure if above TextBox control *also* a culprit behind it...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding generic Edit/Update , why don't you try to assign images and later add a command to them.

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gvProvFooterStyle" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="gvProvFooterStyle" />
                        <FooterStyle CssClass="gvProvFooterStyle footerRow" />
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="ValidateEdt();" ValidationGroup="onUpdate" ImageUrl="~/images/abc.png" CssClass="imagebuttons ibtnStyle" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/abc.png" CssClass="imagebuttons" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/black-edit-24.ico" CssClass="imagebuttons ibtnStyle" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/abc.png" CssClass="imagebuttons" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then assign them width as per your needs. To answer your question, you haven't applied styles to your **edit item template**, just the item template.